# Regex to match plain string with only alphabets as well as optional dot character as beginning of match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex:

```
[:?\.](.+)[\|]?
```

Which successfully matches strings like the below:

```
The data.mws auth token field is required| lalafa daga.lallala
```

Or

```
The data.mws auth token field is required
```

But I'd also like it to match strings like :-

```
This is an error
```

how do I make the `[:?\.]` part optional ? I tried `[:?\.]?` problem is for strings like `The data.mws auth token field is required| lalafa daga.lallala` it will match the `the data` part also, how do I solve this issue.

Comment: Try `(?:^(?!.*[:?.])|[:?.])(.+)[|]?`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hEcVK2/1).

Comment: Hi. Are you sure that regex matches = "The data.mws auth token field is required| lalafa daga.lallala" Your regex begins with either : or ? or .. and the above would not match that.

Comment: @SteveTomlin I don't want the regex to match `The data` at the start of the string , i want the match to start from `.` , and even better if it excludes the `.` , but starts matching from there

Comment: So, `(?:^(?!.*[:?.])|(?<=[:?.]))(.+)[|]?`? See https://regex101.com/r/hEcVK2/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yup , please add as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/(?:^(?!.*[:?.])|(?<=[:?.]))(.+)\|?/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hEcVK2/2)

**Details**

- `(?:^(?!.*[:?.])|(?<=[:?.]))` - either start of string not followed with `:`, `?` and `.` after any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, or a location immediately preceded with `:`, `?` or `.`
- `(.+)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\|?` - an optional `|` char.